# Registering PL/SQL stored function out parameters from Java

Tags: java, jdbc, plsql

I have been given PL SQL stored Function with the following signature and body description.

```
Create or Replace function Get_Employee(user_id in Number, res_out out sys_refcursor)
return  sys_refcursor is
v_result sys_refcursor;
begin
//here goes function body
return v_result
end;
```

Basically, I need to call this function from Java. I have tried all possible ways to register out parameter as well as return value which both are refcursor type. Here is the way which I believe is the most correct way.

```
    String employeeSQL = "{ ? = call Get_Employee(?,?)}";
            CallableStatement statement = null;
            Employee employee = null;
            ResultSet result = null;
    try{
    statement = conn.prepareCall(employeeSQL);
    statement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.Cursor); //registering return value
    statement.registerOutParamter(2, OracleTypes.Cursor); // registering out parameter
    statement .setLong(3, userId); // setting input parameter
    statement.execute();
    resultSet = (ResultSet) statement.getObject(1); // getting return value
    }finally{
    statement.close();
    trsultSet.close();
    }
```

The problem is whenever the statement is executed, it throws NullPointer Exception. So I suspect I do not register parameters in a correct way. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic).

Please provide the *complete* StackTrace or compiler errorr message you get.

Comment: Thanks for the comment,   but it seems like, your answer has nothing to do with my problem @TimothyTruckle .

Comment: well: you state you get an NPE and you did not provide the stacktrace, so I think my comments very well relate to your question.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you suggested statement.setLong(1,userId); statement.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.Cursor); statement.registerOutParamter(3, OracleTypes.Cursor); . If so, I have already tried it, the same error happens. If not pls correct me. @STaefi

Comment: @devgirl: `statement.setLong(2,userId);  statement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.Cursor); statement.registerOutParamter(3, OracleTypes.Cursor);`

Comment: @STaefi  Lots of thanks!!!! It definitely resolved my problem. You might want to post it as an answer.